# Reading a wavefile into a signed float array

Tags: c++, casting, binary, wav

With the following code, I can read the a wave-file into a float array. However, the negative side of the wave ends up on the positive side so: -MAX -> 0 and "-0" -> MAX. I can't quite wrap my head around how to do this properly. I do realize the header portion of the wave may be more than 44 bytes long, but for this application it's not going to happen. I hope one of you fine folks can help me :-)

```
string filename;
getline(cin, filename);

ifstream wavFile(filename, ios::binary | ios::ate);

if (!wavFile) 
    cout << "error reading file\n";

int size = wavFile.tellg();
wavArray = new unsigned char[size];
wavFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
wavFile.read((char *)wavArray, size);
wavFile.close();


int j = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 262; i++)
{
    unsigned int tmp = (wavArray[i + 44] | (wavArray[i + 45] << 8));
    printf("%d : %f \n", k, (tmp / 32768.0));
    j++;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: How are negative values represented in the file?

Comment: Are you sure that you're dealing with 16 bit samples?

Comment: @Pete 0 -> +max, -max -> 0

Comment: @dsp_user Yes :-)

Comment: @soje: Please stop integrating the answers into the question. The question is about the problem you had. When you alter the question in this way, the answers no longer make sense. If you made the suggested changes and have a new problem, ask a new question (after spending some time investigating it, of course!)

Comment: @Lightness Ok, will do, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your use of unsigned for the `tmp` variable. So you never have a negative value in `tmp`, even when the sample is negative. Try this

```
int16_t tmp = (wavArray[i + 44] | (wavArray[i + 45] << 8));
```

You should `#include <cstdint>` to get the `int16_t` type.

Comment: @soje Well as lightness said, time for a new question with the new code.